# How to unstick toolbar on search results page in Oro Commerce?

Tags: orocrm, orocommerce

In Oro Commerce version 4.2 we have sticky toolbar on search results page. How can I make it unsticky?[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the sticky toolbar with the simple [layout update](https://doc.oroinc.com/frontend/storefront/layouts/#dev-doc-frontend-layouts-layout-updates):

```yaml
layout:
    actions:
        - '@remove':
              id: top_sticky_panel
```